# Python Flask: HTML is not rendering

Tags: python, html, flask

***I have an html template that I gave dynamic characteristics to, by using Flask and render_template().***

```
app = Flask(__name__, 8080)
api = Api(app)

class New_Info(Resource):
  def get(self):
    random = exc.runner()
    return render_template('test3.html',book_title=random['title'],book_author=random['author'],book_text=random['text'])

api.add_resource(New_Info, '/pretty')
```

***Everything works but when I view the webpage i get this:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n    <h1>\n        <title>{{book_title}}</title>\n    </h1>\n    <h2>\n        <title>{{book_author}}\n    </h2>\n    <body>\n        <li>{{book_text}}</li>\n    </body>\n</html>
```

***Instead of being properly formatted, like this:***

## A Dark Chapter from New Zealand History

### James Hawthorne

About dawn of the 10th, Major Biggs and family were roused from their beds by a knocking at the back door.  Upon opening it, Major Biggs, who was followed by a servant lad, was immediately shot, and fell whilst telling the lad to get his rifle.  The boy ran to the front door, but was met by a number of Hauhaus.  Making for the back door, he fell over the wounded Major, but got up and ran out into a flax bush.

***How can I fix it so that the html renders properly in a browser?***

***The Python code used to return the html***

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_restful import Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__,8080)
api = Api(app)
class New_Info(Resource):
  def get(self):
    random = exc.runner()
    return render_template('test3.html',book_title=random['title'],book_author=random['author'],book_text=random['text'])
api.add_resource(New_Info, '/pretty')
```

***HTML File***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Random Excerpt</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>
            {{book_title}}
        </h1>
        <h2>
            {{book_author}}
        </h2>

        <div> 
            {{book_text}}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're going to have to show your code for the view function.  Are you viewing this from a url to the view, or as a static file?  May need to show your `app.yaml` as well to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***This code below is used for Restful API, so it returns the render as a string instead of HTML***

```
app = Flask(__name__, 8080)
api = Api(app)

class New_Info(Resource):
  def get(self):
    random = exc.runner()
    return render_template('test3.html',book_title=random['title'],book_author=random['author'],book_text=random['text'])

api.add_resource(New_Info, '/pretty')
```

***This code renders html properly***

```
app = Flask(__name__, 8080)

@app.route('/pretty')
def New_Info():
  random = exc.runner()
  return render_template('test3.html',book_title=random['title'],book_author=random['author'],book_text=random['text'])
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably not the only issue, but this might be due to invalid HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<h1>
<title>{{book_title}}</title>
</h1>
<h2>
<title>{{book_author}}
</h2>
<body>
<li>{{book_text}}</li>
</body>
</html>
```

The `<title>` tag goes in `<head>` and is unique.  The other tags (like `<h1>`) belong in the `<body>`.  Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{book_title}}</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>
            {{book_title}}
        </h1>
        <h2>
            {{book_author}}
        </h2>

        <div> 
            {{book_text}}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Need to see your view function to check the rest of your code.  Perhaps also your `app.yaml`

Comment: I added the function used to call the template and change it. I retried but I am still getting `"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n    <head>\n        <title>Random Excerpt</title>\n    </head>\n\n    <body>\n        <h1>\n            Journals of Dorothy Wordsworth, Vol. 1 (of 2)\n        </h1>\n        <h2>\n            Dorothy Wordsworth\n        </h2>\n\n        <div> \n            He had two patches of new cloth \n        </div>\n    </body>\n</html>"`

Comment: Also, I don't have a app.yaml

Comment: You'll need to show your html templates

Comment: There is only one template, the one used currently is the one you just provided. Here's a link to the working api so you see the output [link](https://engine.stackzbueller.repl.co/api/pretty-restful)

Comment: How are you mapping the request to this Class?  Something is sending the user a string instead of html

Comment: I just found the problem. I originally was using it as restful api, so I went back and changed it from `Class Info(Resource): def get(self): ... ` to just `@app.route('/') def whatever(): return render_template('index.html', {variables} )`. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it!